# How to show only top five labels in e_pie (echarts4r)

Tags: r, echarts4r

Thanks for reading. I am creating a Nightingale Rose Charts using e_pie (echarts4r). I tried to show only top five labels outside the circle but it failed. How can I achieve it?

```
df<-read.table(text='province   revenue
西藏  28
青海  36
新疆  38
内蒙古 40
海南  42
广西  46
吉林  47
黑龙江 49
甘肃  50
宁夏  53
云南  55
山西  65
贵州  68
河北  72
陕西  80
江西  81
河南  82
福建  90
重庆  99
全国  100
辽宁  102
四川  107
湖北  110
天津  117
湖南  128
安徽  135
山东  136
上海  157
浙江  186
北京  203
江苏  247
广东  340
',header=T)

df%>%
  e_charts(x=province)%>%
  e_pie(revenue,roseType='radius',radius=c('5%','80%'), 
        legend = F, 
        label= list(
          position = 'outside',
          formatter= ("{c} ({d})")
        )) %>% 
  e_visual_map(inRange = list(color = c( '#9055A2','#FBFFB9', "#e94e77")))
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the top 5 values of revenue to be plotted separate from the pie graph? Or you just want to plot the top 5 values in the pie graph and nothing else?

Comment: Just the top 5 values in the pie graph and nothing else.

Comment: I posted my answer. Lemme know if it is what youre looking for

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? From what I understand, you are trying to arrange the top 5 values of revenue and plot them:

```
library(tidyverse)

df%>%
  arrange(desc(revenue)) %>% 
  slice(1:5) %>% 
  e_charts(x=province)%>%
  e_pie(revenue,roseType='radius',radius=c('5%','80%'), 
        legend = F, 
        label= list(
          position = 'outside',
          formatter= ("{c} ({d})")
        )) %>% 
  e_visual_map(inRange = list(color = c( '#9055A2','#FBFFB9', "#e94e77")))
```

Like so:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't phrase it clearly. I want a pie chart with full data (not the top 5 values), but only the top 5 labels (when showing all labels, the chart is too cluttered).